# C# Winform : insert url parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert URL into `VARCHAR` column:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DataBase.GetConString());
con.Open();

String query = @"INSERT INTO dbo.PrivateUsers(user) VALUES(@user);";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", url);

int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

This is the user:

```
https://www.instagram.com/blablabla/
```

And I get this exception:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.

Any idea why that's happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**User** is a **reserved T-SQL keyword** and cannot be used just like that - and it's bad practice to use it, anyway.

If you **insist** on using it, then you **must** put it in square brackets:

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO dbo.PrivateUsers([user]) VALUES(@user);";
```